# Error al ejecutar npm install @studydefi/money-legos

Tags: visual-studio

Cuando ejecuto el comando npm install @studydefi/money-legos me sale el siguiente error y no se el porque. Si alguien puede resolver el error.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y cual es el error? Consulta [ask] y realiza el [tour] para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Ya puse la foto lo siento y gracias por responder.

Comment: Aparentemente tienes un problema de permisos sobre la carpeta del proyecto, revisa si la carpeta que está intentando crear ya existe, si existe elimínala y vuelve a ejecutar el comando. En última instancia situa tu proyecto en otra carpeta que no esté dentro del escritorio de windows y vuelve a probar.

Comment: Ya esta solucionado, muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Pues estaría bien que mencionaras como se ha solucionado por si otro usuario tiene el mismo problema en el futuro...

Comment: Si Oscar tambien porque se mantiene en  cola de preguntas

Comment: 7 de marzo: sigue estando en la cola de preguntas :) @FrankCrespo no olvides colocar el error _como texto, con formato_ (no todos pueden ver las imágenes); tampoco olvides responder y [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tal respuesta.